# Curser/Caret deletes while typing

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, caret

I've pressed some combination of button by accident and in doing so caused the cursor/caret to stop working properly. When I type in the editor it replaces what I already have with the new text

For instance, if I have

```
    if(this.class()==foo){...}
```

And I try adding "del" infront of 'this.class()' it comes out as

```
    if(dels.class()==foo){...}
```

How do I turn this effect off? It's not block cursor or selection mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I activated the Insert/overwrite keymap by pressing 'insert'